# Spring boot not reading properties

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

In the main controller, I am able to read the properties. If I have a properties class and try to access these or inject the below values in every class that requires the properties I am unable to do so. what is missing?
I do not want to pass around variables to all the functions from the main controller.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class ApplicationProperties {
    @Autowired
    @Value("${file.location}")
    private String fileLocation;
    
    @Value("${file.name}")
    private String fileName;
    
    /**
     * @return the fileLocation
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String getFileLocation() {
        return fileLocation;
    }
    /**
     * @return the fileName
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="file")
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need the annotation @SpringBootApplication unless the class has main method.

Secondly, you don't need the annotation  @Autowired on fileLocation because @Value is sufficient.

Finally, you need the annotation @RestController because it's a REST api.

Now:

Either add main method to you class and omit @configuration otherwise you need to create a main class with the annotation @SpringBootApplication and keep @RestController.

Comment: I did remove the Autowired as it is not required and SpringBootApplication also. I added those to see if they make any difference. Coming to the above if I use @Value in any of the classes it is not reading what could be the reason. I can ignore the special property reader class also.

Comment: How do you instantiate the instance using new keyword in case it's not RestController? If so you need to annotate the class with Component and autowire it, or you may create a separate class with annotation Configuration to hold your properties

Comment: I am using System.setproperty in the main controller to be able to access from other classes.

Comment: Where to attach? Currently, to move forward I did the value and setting all the properties using System.setproperty in the main controller and accessing in other classes using the system.getproperty. I don't think this is the absolute right way. Let me know if there is a right approach to be able to access the variables directly without that extra push.

Comment: @vijju Try upload to GitHub for example

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach may be:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;

@Component
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${file.location}")
    private String fileLocation;

    @Value("${file.name}")
    private String fileName;

    // ...

}
```

Spring will load properties from *application.properties* by [default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Or you can use specify a different file name in a configuration class using @PropertySource:

```
package com.my.config;

//.. spring imports

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.my.config" })
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class MyConfigClass {

    @Value("${project.name:Default Project Name}")
    private String projectName;

    // giving fileName a default value in case the one specified doesn't exist
    @Value("${file.name:defaultfile.txt}")
    private String fileName;

    //...
}
```

See info on Spring Boot externalized configuration [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config).

Comment: When does the injection happen? If I create an object and access the values, I get null. I am able to use the value and read the properties only in the Main Controller. All other implementation classes I get the values null if I use the value annotation and read or if I use a special class and access from the object getters.

Comment: Is your application.properties in src/main/resources?

Comment: If not, I think you may need to use @ComponentScan

Comment: Any clues from the logs? I think if you run with flag —debug you will get verbose logging that you can use to try to debug why it doesn’t find your properties file.